# Deploying Web service to : Mono 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mono

I developed a webservices using Visual Studio 2008 with C# and C++.

I deploy it to mod_mono, the services is loaded, but when I try to run a method using Invoke button I get the error below, I have tested with MoMA without any error:

```
500 - Internal Server Error

System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for <Module> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method contains unsupported native code

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) <Module>:<CrtImplementationDetails>.ThrowModuleLoadException (string,System.Exception)

  at <Module>.<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport.Initialize (<CrtImplementationDetails>.LanguageSupport* ) [0x00000]

  at <Module>..cctor () [0x00000]

  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

  at I3WebService.Service1.Inferece (System.String value) [0x00000]

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)

  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000]
```

Thank you.

Some more error message, when I use php to call the webservice:

```
(/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mod-mono-server2.exe:1941): WARNING **: Method '<Module>:network.{ctor} (network*)' in assembly '/usr/local/zend/tmp/apache-temp-aspnet-0/54ae108a/assembly/shadow/a7cd17e2/c0c678fa_670b6f18_00000002/engine.dll' contains native code that cannot be executed by Mono on this platform. The assembly was probably created using C++/C
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error messages are plenty clear here.

> contains **native code** that cannot be executed by Mono on this platform. The assembly was probably created using C++/C

You can't use C++/CLI on the Mono platform unless that C++/CLI module was compiled ON that 
Mono platform. Mono itself is platform independent but the native code in your assembly is not.

C++/CLI actually is a way of mixing native code with managed code -- the runtime handles all the P/Invoke stuff behind the scenes but it's still there and you can't forget about it just because it's not directly exposed in the language.